Create order from admin is throwing error after applying the latest Magento 2.4.5-p8 patch and upgrading Maria DB to 10.5
We have applied the recent released Magento 2.4.5-p8 and upgraded Maria DB to 10.5 and facing issue while creating order from admin panel. Upon checking the log, I'm getting below error:

[2024-06-13T07:48:00.032863+00:00] report.CRITICAL: ParseError: syntax error, unexpected token "<<" in /app/pbor5wu32tpvs_stg/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/vendor/magento/module-gift-wrapping/view/adminhtml/templates/order/create/info.phtml:1

Please let me know if any one can help on this.

I did a check with mentioned file and noticed ; missing for script tag in this file. I have added a patch and it seems to be working fine:
    diff --git a/vendor/magento/module-gift-wrapping/view/adminhtml/templates/order/create/info.phtml b/vendor/magento/module-gift-wrapping/view/adminhtml/templates/order/create/info.phtml
index d38324b..b5e8982 100644
--- a/vendor/magento/module-gift-wrapping/view/adminhtml/templates/order/create/info.phtml
+++ b/vendor/magento/module-gift-wrapping/view/adminhtml/templates/order/create/info.phtml
@@ -140,6 +140,6 @@ giftWrappingOrder.setCardPrice(null, {$wrappingPrintedCardValue});
 //]]>
 
 });
-script
+script;
 ?>
 <?= /* @noEscape */ $secureRenderer->renderTag('script', [], $scriptString, false); ?>

Update vendor/magento/module-gift-wrapping/view/adminhtml/templates/order/create/info.phtml and replace script with script; at line number 143.
It should fix the issue.
